# Sum of positive elements in linked list

Tags: ruby, arrays, linked-list, sum

I need to make program, but i can't finish it and get into mess with methods.
The aim is to find the sum of all positive of elements and add it in the end. I am just started teach classes and methods.

How can I make the sum of all positive elements in my final array?

Here is my code:

```
class Node

    attr_accessor :value, :next_node

    def initialize val,next_in_line
        @value = val
        @next_nodex = next_in_line
        puts "Initialized a Node with value:  " + value.to_s 
    end
end

class LinkedList

    def initialize val
        @head = Node.new(val,nil)
    end

    def add(value)
        current = @head
        while current.next_node != nil
            current = current.next_node
        end 
        current.next_node = Node.new(value,nil)
        self    
    end

    def delete(val)
        current = @head
        if current.value == val
            @head = @head.next_node
        else
            current = @head
            while (current != nil) && (current.next_node != nil) && ((current.next_node).value != val)
                current = current.next_node
            end 

            if (current != nil) && (current.next_node != nil)
                current.next_node = (current.next_node).next_node
            end
        end
    end

    def display
        current = @head
        full_list = [] 
        while current.next_node != nil 
            full_list += [current.value.to_s]
            current = current.next_node
        end
        full_list += [current.value.to_s]
        puts full_list.join(" ")
    end
    def sum

    end
end


puts "\n"
list = [*-99..99].shuffle
ll = LinkedList.new(list[0])

(1..9).each do |i|
   ll.add(list[i])
end

puts "\nDo you want item to add? '1' - yes '0' - no"
adding = gets.to_i
puts "\n"
if adding == 1
    ll.add(list[10])
    end


puts "\nDisplaying Linked List:"
ll.display

puts "\nDo you want to delete item? '1' - yes '0' - no"
deleting = gets.to_i

if deleting == 1   
puts "Type in and delete item and then display the linked list:"
deleteInt = gets.to_i
ll.delete(deleteInt)
 end
puts ll.display

puts "\nThe sum of all positive elements"
ll.sum
```

Comment: You need to provide *a question*.

Comment: You create an array call `list` the contains 199 integers between -99 and 99 (shuffled).  You then create an instance `ll` of `LinkedList`, passing the first element of `list`.  That does not give `ll` access to `list`, only to the first element, which is an integer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I didn't understand correctly... I created list which has 10 initial elements. But how to connect all this ll and list in case to receive the sum of all positive integers of list array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, You have mistype in `Node.initialize` method - `@next_nodex` should be `@next_node` i think. Secondly, don't use `puts` 2 times: `puts ll.display` at the end. To add in array preferably use `<<` symbol.

Another thing, i can't see any concept difference between `display` and `sum` methods, except one condition. According to this, it should be like:

```
def sum
  current = @head
  sum = 0
  while current.next_node != nil
    sum += current.value if current.value > 0
    current = current.next_node
  end
  sum += current.value if current.value > 0
  sum
end
```

or with dry:

```
def full_list
  current = @head
  full_list = []
  while current.next_node != nil
    full_list << current.value
    current = current.next_node
  end
  full_list << current.value
  full_list
end

def display
  puts full_list.join(' ')
end

def sum
  full_list.keep_if { |x| x > 0 }.reduce(:+)
end
```

[All code](https://gist.github.com/zishe/b5339c0efe82518a64cf)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it is all clear! You really helped me in teaching classes and methods.